# How to trigger router Guards without changing page

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-guards

I am using Angular 9 (Ivy). I want to trigger router Guards without actually changing the page. With the current abilities of Angular, how can I accomplish this?

This following is example code that does *not* work but should give an idea of what I am trying to do.

In the template:

```
<button type="button" (click)="triggerGuards()">Trigger</button>
```

In the component:

```
public triggerGuards(): void {
    // this `navigate()` call does *not* trigger Guards //
    this._router.navigate([this._router.url]).then(() => {
        this._doSomethingElse();
    });
}
```

I also tried `this._router.navigateByUrl(this._router.url + '?')` but this does not fire the Guards either.

How can I trigger router Guards without changing pages?

Comment: runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'

Try setting this in routing module where u configured your guards. Also u may need to set onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'